# Link to other page in Drupal 8

Tags: php, twig, block, drupal-8, base-url

In Drupal 7, I used following codes to link to other pages. I have "**Service**" **block** and inside that block , I write like this.

```
<?php
global $base_url;    
global $base_path;   
$link = $base_url . '/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_business/images';
?>
<div><img alt="" src="<?php print $link?>/customer.png" /></div>
<p><a href="<?php echo $base_url;?>/en/test#collapseOne"> Service</a></p>
```

and I save text format with **PHP**. 
But for now **Drupal 8**, we don't have Text format option "PHP" and also I don't know how to write codes to connect with other page.  
Anyone help me please?  
 Thanks.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-block check doc how to create custom block programmatically, now you can use PHP to generate your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In drupal 8 you can use  hook_preprocess_HOOK() to pass variables to twig files and call your variables like

```
<header class="main-header">
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if page.header and logged_in %}
    {{ page.header }}
  {% endif %}
  {% if not logged_in %}
  <a href="{{ front_page }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home" id="logo" class="logo">
    <img src="{{ base_path }}themes/custom/mytheme/logo-login.png" alt="{{ 'Home'|t }}" />
  </a>
  <h2 class="login-logo">{{ site_name }}</h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}
</header>
```

Please see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates for more details

You can also include other pages using

```
{# this template is located in templates/layout.html.twig #}
{% extends "layout.html.twig" %}

{# this template is located in templates/user/profile.html.twig #}
{{ include('user/profile.html.twig') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

See: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates

In your example, you need to specify your theme directory. Just use:

```
<img src="/{{ directory }}/images/xyz.jpg">
```

Here, {{directory }} will resolve to directory of your current theme.
For preparing links to other fields. see above mentioned drupal page